# Nested ERB template layouts like Liquid?

Tags: templates, layout, nested, erb, liquid

With [Liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org/), you can nest layouts. E.g., [my site's](http://www.mattdipasquale.com/) [default layout](https://github.com/mattdipasquale/mattdipasquale.github.com/blob/master/_layouts/default.html) builds off of the [base layout](https://github.com/mattdipasquale/mattdipasquale.github.com/blob/master/_layouts/base.html).

Is this possible with [ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/classes/ERB.html)? If so, how?

I'm asking because I'm migrating a [GitHub Pages](http://pages.github.com/) site to [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), so that I can handle forms natively (not with [Wufoo](http://www.wufoo.com/) or [Google Forms](https://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=87809)).

Comment: Do you mean how do you do this in **HAML**? Since Sinatra has support for Liquid.

Comment: @phoffer yes, although now I'm wondering how to do it in ERB (but HAML would be cool too), I edited the question to make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

make a file called layout.haml (or erb or whatever your templates are in), and put it in the views folder. this is your site layout, and it could look like this (I'm using haml):

```
 %html
  %head 
    %link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css")  
  %body
    %div.outer
      %div.inner
        = yield
```

the magic part is the `=yield`
this is where Sinatra will render whatever template you call in your route. the = tells your template to expect ruby code.

for example, if your route is

```
get '/' do 
  haml :index
end
```

then your template at /views/index.haml will be inserted. you can also use a custom layout if you tell your template to override the one at /views/layout.haml.

hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this shows how to use one layout file. But, how do you nest two or more layout files? Please reread my question as I've revised it.